# Question about Schwarz's theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've read that given a smooth function $f(x,y)$,

$∂f/∂x∂y = ∂f/∂y∂x$

Question: is the following also true if $f(x,t)$:

$∂f/∂t∂x = ∂f/∂x∂t$

I am wondering if the above is true because time is not a spatial variable.

Comment: Totally not a relevant issue. Yes, if you have a $C^2$ function, then mixed partials with respect to any two variables are always equal.

Comment: Just notice that the "difference" between your two equations is just a matter of notation.

Comment: Thank you, both!

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin and Amelia, just a follow-up on my question above. Suppose I have a smooth function $F(x,y,t)$, is the following equality also true?

(∂x/∂t)(∂f/∂y)=(∂x/∂y)(∂f/∂t)

But then since x and y are spatial variables the equality above is just zero? Thank you!

Comment: Only if the variables are truly independent. If they are constrained by some equation $F=0$, then it is complicated.

Comment: Thank you, @TedShifrin!